# Inclusion of Sobolev spaces (from a proof by Bogachev - Krylov - Röckner - Shaposhnikov)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

In a book by Bogachev-Krylov-Rockner-Shaposhnikov, I found the following statement that concludes a proof but I do not understand. I underlined in red the critical parts.

[image]

$\rho(\cdot,t)>0$ is a probability density function solving a certain parabolic PDE in a weak sense. The function $f_\epsilon$ approximates $\rho(\cdot,t)$ as $\epsilon\to0$, precisely:
$$ f_\epsilon(x,t) \,:=\, \big(\rho(\cdot,t)*w_\epsilon\big)(x) \,+\, \epsilon\,\max(1,|x|)^{-d-1}$$
where $w_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\epsilon^2)^{d/2}}\,e^{-|x|^2/(2\epsilon^2)}\,$.
The Sobolev space $W^{2,1}$ denotes those functions with weak derivatives up to the first order belonging to $L^2$ (notice that the indices of differentiability and integrability are reversed with respect to "usual" notation).

**How can I deduce the last red statement**?

The **first red part** is clear, since
$$\nabla \sqrt{\rho(\cdot,t)} \,=\, \frac{1}{2}\,\frac{\nabla\rho(\cdot,t)}{\sqrt{\rho(\cdot,t)}}$$
hence the approximation argument shows that this weak gradient exists and belongs to $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$.

Now, since $\rho(\cdot,t)>0$ is a probability density function (by hypothesis), the **second red part** follows from the first red part by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} |\nabla\rho(x,t)|\,d x \,\leq\, \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{|\nabla\rho(x,t)|^2}{\rho(x,t)}\,d x \ \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb R^d} \rho(x,t)\,d x}_{=\,1} \ <\infty $$
for almost all $t\in(0,\tau)$, hence $\rho(\cdot,t)\in W^{1,1}(\mathbb R^d)$ for almost all $t\in(0,\tau)$.

I don't understand why the **last red statement** holds true.
$\sqrt{\rho}\in\mathbb H^{2,2}$ means -by definition of this space- that $\partial_i\partial_j \sqrt{\rho(\cdot,t)}\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ for almost all $t\in(0,\tau)$ and
$$\int_0^\tau \int|\partial_i\partial_j \sqrt{\rho(x,t)}|^2 d x\, dt <\infty\,.$$
Why this is the case? Why the weak second derivatives even exist?

*Edit.* **The full reference is Theorem 7.4.1 in the book "Fokker-Planck-Kolmogorov equations" by Bogachev, Krylov, Röckner, Shaposhnikov.** Here's the statement:

[image]

Comment: Does $\rho$ or it's square root satisfy an equation of some type? This might be where the gain in regularity's coming from, but I think regardless we need more context about what $\rho$ is.

Comment: @Jose27 $\rho>0$ is the density function of the probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ which solves (in a weak sense) a Cauchy problem for a parabolic PDE $\partial_t \mu = L^* \mu$ where $L^*$ is a non-degenerate elliptic operator. But the aim of this Theorem should be precisely to prove some regularity for $\rho$. I wonder if there is a mistake and one should read $\mathbb H^{2,1}$ instead of $\mathbb H^{2,2}$.

Comment: Could you post the theorem and proof in full? I think it'd really help clarify some things.

Comment: @Jose27 I'm not sure: it's 4 pages proof. Maybe I can give the reference?

Comment: For sure the reference please, and if you think the proof is too long, at least post the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @Jose27, done !